# Google Protocol Buffers - setting a field.

Tags: c#, file, serialization, protocol-buffers, memorystream

I'm using Google Protocol Buffers with C# and I'm unable to set a field for an object I have. I have two .proto files: filepath.proto and filepaths.proto. Filepaths.proto contains a repeated field for Filepath.proto messages. Here are both files:

```
// filepath.proto

syntax = "proto3";
package TEST;

message FilePath
{
   string path = 1;
}

// filepaths.proto
syntax = "proto3";
import "filepath.proto";
package TEST;

message FilePaths
{
   repeated FilePath file_path = 1;
}
```

I know how to create FilePath objects:

As you can see, the FilePaths message uses several FilePath objects. I know how to create several FilePath objects using:

```
Google.Protobuf.Collections.RepeatedField<FilePath> filepaths = new Google.Protobuf.Collections.RepeatedField<FilePath>();
filepaths.Add(fp1);
filepaths.Add(fp2);
filepaths.Add(fp3);
filepaths.Add(fp4);
filepaths.Add(fp5);
```

where fp1, fp2, fp3, fp4, and fp5 are FilePath objects I created earlier in code. I create the FilePaths object like this:

```
FilePaths fpTest = new FilePaths
{
    Path = filepaths // ERROR HERE
};
```

Visual Studio tells me that the field "Paths" of FilePaths is read-only, i.e., I only get a GET, not a SET. Is there anyway around this or a way to fix this? Basically I'm trying to create a FilePaths object that contains several FilePath objects.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. All you have to do is set the field and place it in bracket. So in my example I would need to do this:

```
FilePaths fpTest = new FilePaths
{
    Path = { filepaths }
};
```